# How to count only 4 integers from an input - JAVA

Tags: java, validation, input, integer

Hey just doing a project for school and wondering how to restrict the user to only input a 4 integer input for the zip code. eg: (1454)

```
    while (count == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Input a postcode for us to send you the package: ");
        try
        {
            postage = in.nextInt();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("This is an invalid input!");
            in.next();
            continue;
        }
        if (postage >= 0000 && postage <= 9999)
        {
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should read the input and if it is too long, just ask again?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to take the Input as a String, and then only converting the first four characters to int(parseInt()) and using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.matches(String regex)` method with regex `\\d{4}` to check if the input is 4 digit:

```
// ---
if(String.valueOf(postage).matches("\\d{4}")) {
    System.out.println(" ");
}
// ---
```

About regex:

- `\\d` : digit
- `{4}` : to match 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use while:

```
while(!(postage >= 0000 && postage <= 9999)){
     System.out.println("This is an invalid input!");
     postage = in.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Which will result in an infinite loop. You need to update the variable inside of the loop.